# R: How do we print percentage accuracy for SVM

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, libsvm, confusion-matrix

Here is my sample `R` code:

```
    train <- read.csv("Train.csv")
    test <- read.csv("Test+.csv")

   x <- model.matrix(age ~ . - 1,data=train)           

    classify=svm(as.factor(age)~ ., data=train,method="class")
    pred = predict(classify,test,type="class")
```

How could I print percentage accuracy from this? I want to display all the performance metrics like accuracy, precision, recall .etc for my evaluation.

Comment: Define accuracy--there are multiple valid accuracy metrics for classification.

Comment: I don't think it applies for a classification problem.  An outcome is either in a category or it's not.

Answer (score 8):

Here are a couple of options, using the built-in `iris` data frame for illustration:

```
library(e1071)

m1 <- svm(Species ~ ., data = iris)
```

Create confusion matrix using `table` function:

```
table(predict(m1), iris$Species, dnn=c("Prediction", "Actual"))
```

> ```
>             Actual
> Prediction   setosa versicolor virginica
> setosa         50          0         0
> versicolor      0         48         2
> virginica       0          2        48
> ```

Use the `caret` package to generate the confusion matrix and other model diagnostics (you can also use [`caret` for the entire model development, tuning and validation process](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html)):

```
library(caret)

confusionMatrix(iris$Species, predict(m1))
```

> ```
> Confusion Matrix and Statistics
>
>             Reference
> Prediction   setosa versicolor virginica
> setosa         50          0         0
> versicolor      0         48         2
> virginica       0          2        48
>
> Overall Statistics
>
> Accuracy : 0.9733          
> 95% CI : (0.9331, 0.9927)
> No Information Rate : 0.3333          
> P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16       
>
> Kappa : 0.96            
> Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA              
>
> Statistics by Class:
>
>                      Class: setosa Class: versicolor Class: virginica
> Sensitivity                 1.0000            0.9600           0.9600
> Specificity                 1.0000            0.9800           0.9800
> Pos Pred Value              1.0000            0.9600           0.9600
> Neg Pred Value              1.0000            0.9800           0.9800
> Prevalence                  0.3333            0.3333           0.3333
> Detection Rate              0.3333            0.3200           0.3200
> Detection Prevalence        0.3333            0.3333           0.3333
> Balanced Accuracy           1.0000            0.9700           0.9700
> ```

Comment: @Mahsolid "how to tune" is a completely different question from "how to print percentage accuracy".